# "Multithreaded execution was detected" when using context.CallHttpAsyn

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an OrchestrationTrigger function that call another service by http request.

```
 [FunctionName("MyFunc")]
        public async Task RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        var req = new DurableHttpRequest(HttpMethod.Post, _uri, headers, jsonBody);
        var res = await context.CallHttpAsync(req);
        // Do something
    }
```

but get the following error:

> Multithreaded execution was detected. This can happen if the
>   orchestrator function code awaits on a task that was not created by a
>   DurableOrchestrationContext method. More details can be found in this
>   article
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay#orchestrator-code-constraints.

the official documentation there suggest to use  `context.CallHttpAsync` - exactly what I've did.

Answer (score 5):

When a `IDurableOrchestrationContext` method throws this exception, it means that you called the method using a thread other than the orchestrator thread. The problem here isn't necessarily with the `CallHttpAsync` call, but rather the fact that something else in your code spun up a new thread. In most cases, this is caused by an illegal `await` statement in  some *previous* line of code - e.g. `await Task.Delay(1000)`.

If you can update your post with your full orchestration description, then we should be able to more easily point out where the problem is.

Also, consider using the [Durable Functions Roslyn Analyzer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers/) to help detect these types of coding mistakes proactively (there will be a new version available later this week which fixes a bunch of known issues).

Answer (score -1):

I've upgraded Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions and the issue disapeared